How to read master->detail rows?
I have 2 tables T1(master), T2(detail). CDC works on these both
tables.
I'd like to restore history tables to th new 2 tables T11->T21 using stored procedure.
The question is: how to process the history tables correctly?
If I get and process all T1 history records and after it all T2 there is can be referential integrity conflict.
For example: my SP processes all master rows: D, I, D, I and then details from the start to end of the history.
What is  the best way?

Use net changes? or first apply changes and then create constraints

Apply changes and then create constraints sounds good but it is permanent process : begin: source tables are changing, change history appears in CDC tables, Job executes SP which gets changes and applies to the target tables and go to begin....

I even ready to process master table history in cursor row by row but the question: how to get from the detail history records corresponding this master record from history?

I think you're saying that after you write changes to MasterHistory table, some of those changes are deletions. Therefore when you write to DetailHistory you get foreign key violations because of the deletions from MasterHistory - is that right? If so, then you can leave the "deleted" rows in MasterHistory by adding a deleted column (bool). Alternatively, when writing to DetailHistory, join the incoming change rows to the rows in MasterHistory before doing the insert. You can also set the foreign key to on delete cascade so that MasterHistory deletions don't fail.

Hi @allmhuran, write your comment as an answer, I will mark it.

Hi @allmhuran, thank you for your help, but yet one thing: with insert, deletes I have made as you recommended. It works, but how to process Updates? They should be replayed in the same chronological order as they were done. I should read row by row and replay them? How to read in order of they happen?
